# Error while I'm pressing button

Tags: android

I see that this problem is general, I search for it, but no response to what's happening at me.

Here is the Log Cat:

```
05-10 19:42:31.564: E/AndroidRuntime(2839): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 19:42:31.564: E/AndroidRuntime(2839): Process: com.blabla.quiztest, PID: 2839
05-10 19:42:31.564: E/AndroidRuntime(2839): java.lang.IllegalStateException: **Could not find a method setupMessageButton(View) in the activity class com.blabla.quiztest.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button1'**
05-10 19:42:31.564: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3810)
05-10 19:42:31.564: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
05-10 19:42:31.564: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
05-10 19:42:31.564: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-10 19:42:31.564: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-10 19:42:31.564: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-10 19:42:31.564: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-10 19:42:31.564: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 19:42:31.564: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-10 19:42:31.564: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-10 19:42:31.564: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-10 19:42:31.564: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-10 19:42:31.564: E/AndroidRuntime(2839): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: setupMessageButton [class android.view.View]
05-10 19:42:31.564: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
05-10 19:42:31.564: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:857)
05-10 19:42:31.564: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3803)
05-10 19:42:31.564: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):     ... 11 more
```

**The MainActivity.xml**

```
package com.blabla.quiztest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

> ```
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>     if (savedInstanceState == null) {
>         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
>                 .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
>                 .commit();
>     }
> }
>
>
> public void setupMessageButton() {
>   Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
>   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>       public void onClick(View view) {
>           // Do something in response to button click
>           //Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
>           Context context = getApplicationContext();
>           CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
>           int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
>
>           Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
>           toast.show();
>       }
>   });
> }
>
>
> @Override
> public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
>
>     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
>     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
>     return true;
> }
>
> @Override
> public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
>     // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
>     // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
>     // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
>     int id = item.getItemId();
>     if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
>         return true;
>     }
>     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
> }
>
> /**
>  * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
>  */
> public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
>
>     public PlaceholderFragment() {
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
>             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
>         return rootView;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> }

In **fragment_main.xml**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="189dp"
    android:onClick="setupMessageButton"
    android:text="Button" />
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

2 solutions:

Put this in your oncreate:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View view) {
          // Do something in response to button click
          //Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
          Context context = getApplicationContext();
          CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
          int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

          Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
          toast.show();
      }
```

OR put replace everything setupmessagebutton() with:

You would also need to change setupmessagebutton() to setupmessagebutton(View view)

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
          CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
          int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

          Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
          toast.show();
```

I would go with the second solution but it is up to you.

EDIT: The problem is you define an onclick callback in XML, you don't need to set an OnClickListener in your code.

Answer (score 1):

When you use an `onClick` listener with its attribute `android:onClick="foo"`, the method has to use in its parameter the `View` which has been clicked. As follows:

```
public void setupMessageButton(View view) {  
    ...
}
```

As you can see in [the Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#HandlingEvents) (in the first part):

> The method you declare in the android:onClick attribute must have a signature exactly as shown above. Specifically, the method must:
>   - Be public
>   - Return void
>   - **Define a View as its only parameter (this will be the View that was clicked)**

Finally, you use the attribute in the xml then you don't need to call `setOnClickListener` method in your `Activity`, because the system already uses `OnClickListener` by using this attribute.
Then, your method needs to be:

```
public void setupMessageButton(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button click
    //Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
}
```

Also, if you want to update or use the `View` pressed on the click event, use the variable like:

```
public void foo(View view) {
    // view = the view clicked.
    view.setText("Clicked");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The message says it's looking for a method like this:

```
setupMessageButton(View)
```

You have defined this:

```
public void setupMessageButton() {
```

You need to add a `View` parameter:

```
public void setupMessageButton(View view) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be concerned with this line in your LogCat:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: **Could not find a method setupMessageButton(View) in the activity class com.blabla.quiztest.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button1'**
```

Notice this:

`Could not find a method setupMessageButton(View)...for onClick handler on view class`

This is because you have used `android:onClick="setupMessageButton"` in your XML but have not created the corresponding method to that action in your class.

You created `public void setupMessageButton()` but as the error log states, it's looking for the `View` parameter.

So change this:

```
public void setupMessageButton() {
```

to this:

```
public void setupMessageButton(View view) {
```

The method just needs the `View` parameter to be "recognized".

Comment: Works now, thanks, but It's there a issue when the first button is pressed doesn't show me the message, while the second pressed works well ?